# Segmentation fault на linux при считывании строк файла

Tags: c++, linux

Есть код по считыванию строк из файла

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {    
    int i=0;
    string s[4]; 
    ifstream file("/home/pip/sik"); 

    while(getline(file, s[i])){ 
        cout << s[i] << endl; 
        i++;
    }
    file.close(); 

}
```

Опишу свои действия ,тк только начал в этом разбираться :
1.

```
touch program.cpp
```

2.

```
nano program.cpp
```

и пишу туда этот код
3.

```
g++ -lm -o output program.cpp
```

Он все вроде бы работает ,но после того ,как выводит s[i](проходит весь цикл,не одна строка) пишет "Segmentation fault" и дальше какие бы действия я не добавил в код , они не выполняются.В чем проблема?
Спасибо за внимание=)

Comment: Ну так а сколько строк в вашем файле? Почему массив имеет размер именно `[4]`?

Comment: в моем файле 4 строки

Comment: Ну так может там и пятая в конце затесалась - пустая?

Comment: хм ,все заработало .
На винде при s[4] все работало , на Linux заработало при s[5] ,хотя файлы одинаковые.

Comment: Работало **по счастливой случайности**. А вообще, `man realloc`.

Comment: Привыкайте работать с полезными контейнерами на подобии std::vector или учитесь отлаживать свой код если вам так нужны массивы. Ошибка просто из за неопытности